# Undefined index: frontName in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config.php

Tags: magento2, php, index, undefined

I've not found something that could help me in other topis :(

My problem is correlated to creation of pages, when I try to create a new Page in **Content->Pages->New Page** i receive this error :

> Notice: Undefined index: frontName in
> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config.php on
> line 123

Next there's the code of App/Route/Config.php if it could be helpful :

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration model
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\App\Route;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class Config implements ConfigInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config\Reader
     */
    protected $_reader;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface
     */
    protected $_cache;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cacheId;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Config\ScopeInterface
     */
    protected $_configScope;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList
     */
    protected $_areaList;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_routes;

    /**
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * @param Config\Reader $reader
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface $cache
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\ScopeInterface $configScope
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList $areaList
     * @param string $cacheId
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config\Reader $reader,
        \Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface $cache,
        \Magento\Framework\Config\ScopeInterface $configScope,
        \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList $areaList,
        $cacheId = 'RoutesConfig'
    ) {
        $this->_reader = $reader;
        $this->_cache = $cache;
        $this->_cacheId = $cacheId;
        $this->_configScope = $configScope;
        $this->_areaList = $areaList;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch routes from configs by area code and router id
     *
     * @param string $scope
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getRoutes($scope = null)
    {
        $scope = $scope ?: $this->_configScope->getCurrentScope();
        if (isset($this->_routes[$scope])) {
            return $this->_routes[$scope];
        }
        $cacheId = $scope . '::' . $this->_cacheId;
        $cachedRoutes = $this->_cache->load($cacheId);
        if ($cachedRoutes) {
            $cachedRoutes = $this->getSerializer()->unserialize($cachedRoutes);
            if (is_array($cachedRoutes)) {
                $this->_routes[$scope] = $cachedRoutes;
                return $cachedRoutes;
            }
        }

        $routers = $this->_reader->read($scope);
        $routes = $routers[$this->_areaList->getDefaultRouter($scope)]['routes'] ?? null;
        $routesData = $this->getSerializer()->serialize($routes);
        $this->_cache->save($routesData, $cacheId);
        $this->_routes[$scope] = $routes;
        return $routes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve route front name
     *
     * @param string $routeId
     * @param null|string $scope
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteFrontName($routeId, $scope = null)
    {
        $routes = $this->_getRoutes($scope);
        return isset($routes[$routeId]) ? $routes[$routeId]['frontName'] : $routeId;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @param string $frontName
     * @param string $scope
     * @return bool|int|string
     */
    public function getRouteByFrontName($frontName, $scope = null)
    {
        foreach ($this->_getRoutes($scope) as $routeId => $routeData) {
            if ($routeData['frontName'] == $frontName) {
                return $routeId;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @param string $frontName
     * @param string $scope
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getModulesByFrontName($frontName, $scope = null)
    {
        $routes = $this->_getRoutes($scope);
        $modules = [];
        foreach ($routes as $routeData) {
            if ($routeData['frontName'] == $frontName && isset($routeData['modules'])) {
                $modules = $routeData['modules'];
                break;
            }
        }

        return array_unique($modules);
    }

    /**
     * Get serializer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     * @deprecated 101.0.0
     */
    private function getSerializer()
    {
        if ($this->serializer === null) {
            $this->serializer = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(SerializerInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->serializer;
    }
}
```

Someone could help me? thank you in advice guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "frontName" property is most likely missing in the routes.xml file of one of your custom modules.

Here is how it should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="myroute" frontName="myroute">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Edit**

For a fast debugging, I would change the Config.php file in line 123:

```
/**
     * @param string $frontName
     * @param string $scope
     * @return bool|int|string
     */
    public function getRouteByFrontName($frontName, $scope = null)
    {
        foreach ($this->_getRoutes($scope) as $routeId => $routeData) {
// this is new
if(!isset($routeData['frontName'])) {
var_dump($routeId);
var_dump($routeData);
die;
}
            if ($routeData['frontName'] == $frontName) {
                return $routeId;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This should give you enough information to search your code and find the error's root cause.

Note that, although the error is *thrown* in the core, the root cause is most likely a wrong configuration in another file which is read during that process.

Comment: Hi Simon, it's more a problem of not a custom module but with a fraemwork of Magento, i really don't know in what route.xml i can place this since it's more like a system problem... any suppose? And thank u for the help in any case!

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Good Simon, with the log error i've found that the problem was in a new module imported into magento. The "fix" is return back to a commit without that module. Thank u a lot!

Comment: You’re welcome.